# 2d motion simulator for given differential equations

Tags: simulation, physics, gravity, differential-equations, orbit

Phet has a really neat simulation [here](https://phet.colorado.edu/en/simulation/gravity-and-orbits) for gravitation orbits that you can play around with. Are there any other simulations out there that let you do the same, but also allow you to play around with the equations of motion? (ie. diff equations). I think it would make for  great learning tool to see how gravity would function if instead of being a 1/r^2 force, it was 1/r or r or sqrt(r), etc...

Thanks.

Comment: So, what's the question here?

Answer (score 1):

Mathematical tools like [matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/index.html) (alternatively [scilab](http://www.scilab.org/) or [octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/)) or [mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) (alternatively [sage](http://www.sagemath.org/) or [wxmaxima](http://andrejv.github.io/wxmaxima/)) propose ODE solving stuff / integration tools, I guess you can have a look at them. You can use them to integrate your equations then plot them and deduce the different behaviours. This will always be "less graphical" though.

The MIT youtube channel has a course about Differential Equations, with some videos about matlab tools, you can have a look at them [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZvL88xqYSak&list=PLUl4u3cNGP63oTpyxCMLKt_JmB0WtSZfG)